# "react-native run-ios" command line does not work

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

**Description**

First error:

error Failed to build iOS project. We ran “xcodebuild” command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening awesome.xcworkspace.

couple of warnings:

warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target’s Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target ‘React-jsiexecutor’ from project ‘Pods’)
warning: None of the architectures in ARCHS (i386, x86_64) are valid. Consider setting ARCHS to $(ARCHS_STANDARD) or updating it to include at least one value from VALID_ARCHS (i386, x86_64) which is not in EXCLUDED_ARCHS (x86_64). (in target ‘React-jsiexecutor’ from project ‘Pods’)

last error:

The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Copy\ XCFrameworks /Users/sammie/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/awesome-fgqovmpltvmybwfboirbhkzybyqx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OpenSSL-Universal.build/Script-329FE3CB18B30DBF34BE47031BE8F397.sh
(1 failure)

**React Native version:**

```
OS: macOS 10.15
CPU: (6) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9400F CPU @ 2.90GHz
Memory: 321.19 MB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 14.17.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.10 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 6.14.13 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.10.1 - /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
Android SDK:
API Levels: 30
Build Tools: 30.0.3, 31.0.0
System Images: android-29 | Android TV Intel x86 Atom, android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
Android NDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: 4.2 AI-202.7660.26.42.7351085
Xcode: 11.2/11B52 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: 1.8.0_292 - /usr/bin/javac
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1
react-native: 0.64.2 => 0.64.2
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
react-native: Not Found
```

**Steps To Reproduce**

What I did:

-remove react-native cli globally and reinstall it.

-delete pods and pod lock files and reinstall pods

-commented some lines in pod file

-deleted "build" directory

-...

**Expected Results**

react native run ios command line works properly.